# Saving E-Mails with Meeting Invitation From Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the following VBA code macro to save all selected e-mails in .msg format to any folder but it doesn't save emails with meeting invitations. How do I also save mails with meeting invitations? Do I have to include any special objects? Below is the code that I am using to save the e-mails in .msg format:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SaveMessageAsMsg()

Dim xShell As Object
Dim xFolder As Object
Dim strStartingFolder As String
Dim xFolderItem As Object

Dim xMail As MailItem
Dim xObjItem As Object

Dim xPath As String
Dim xFileName As String
Dim xName As String
Dim xDtDate As Date

Set xShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

On Error Resume Next
' Bypass error when xFolder is nothing on Cancel
Set xFolder = xShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select a folder:", 0, strStartingFolder)
' Remove error bypass as soon as the purpose is served
On Error GoTo 0

If Not TypeName(xFolder) = "Nothing" Then
    Set xFolderItem = xFolder.Self
    xFileName = xFolderItem.Path
    ' missing path separator
    If Right(xFileName, 1) <> "\" Then xFileName = xFileName & "\"
Else
    xFileName = ""
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each xObjItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection

    If xObjItem.Class = olMail Then

        Set xMail = xObjItem

        xName = Left(CleanFileName(xMail.Subject), 100)
        Debug.Print xName

        xDtDate = xMail.ReceivedTime

        xName = Format(xDtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
          vbUseSystem) & "-" & xName & ".msg"

        xPath = xFileName & xName

        xMail.SaveAs xPath, olMSG
    End If
Next

End Sub

Public Function CleanFileName(strFileName As String) As String

Dim Invalids
Dim e
Dim strTemp As String

Invalids = Array("?", "*", ":", "|", "<", ">", "[", "]", """", "/", "\")

strTemp = strFileName

For Each e In Invalids
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, e, " ")
    'strTemp = Replace(strTemp, e, "")
Next

CleanFileName = strTemp

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code posted above only mail items are handled:

```
 If xObjItem.Class = olMail Then
```

There are various object types in Outlook, see [OlObjectClass enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olobjectclass) for more information.

Basically, you need to handle also meeting items:

```
Dim xMail As Object
If xObjItem.Class = olMail Or xObjItem.Class = olMeetingRequest Then
```

Comment: I tried that but I get the Type mismatch (Error 13) error

Comment: Nevermind, it works now. I didn't clarify xMail as an Object. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am glad that my post helped.